# Constructing a sequence $\{ f_n \} \subset C_{c}[0,1]$ such that ..

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, sequence-of-function

Constructing a sequence $\{ f_n \} \subset C_{c}[0,1]$(the space of continuous functions with compact support in $[0,1]$) such that ..

$(a)$ $||{f_n}||_{\infty} \to \infty$ and $||{f_n}||_{1} \to 0.$

Here is my sequence:    $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 
      n + nx, & \text{ if }  0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n^2},\\
      0, &  \text{ if } x > \frac{1}{n^2}.
   \end{cases}$

My calculations said that I am correct in this sequence. **right?**

$(b)$ $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x$ and $||{f_n}||_{1} \to \infty.$

Here is a solution to it:

> [image]

But I feel like the given function is not correct when $x = \frac{1}{2n},$ **am I correct?** **If so, what is the intuition behind creating this function correctly? Does anyone one know a function that works?**

Can anyone help me answer these questions please?

Comment: They seem to be talking about pointwise convergence rather than uniform convergence so $x$ is fixed.

Comment: So what iif the fixed value of $x$ was $1/2n$?@Manifoldski

Comment: Then you would need a different letter for the sequence. It can not be the same $n$ as the $n$ in $f_{n}(x)$ in the pointwise case. If $x=1/2n$ you would look at $f_{1}(1/2n),f_{2}(1/2n),f_{3}(1/2n),\dots,f_{m}(1/2n),\dots$ for instance which is eventually zero.

Comment: @Manifoldski  I did not get your point, why $f_i(1/2n)$ is eventually zero?

Comment: Pick $i$ large enough that $1/i < 1/2n$ then $f_{m}(1/2n) =0$ for all $m>i$ by definition of $f_{j}(x)$.

Comment: Your comments read to me like you want to do the uniform convergence. That is, you want to say that $f_{n}(1/2n) = n^{2}$ is not going zero, this is true, but(!) it requires you to have fixed $n$ before choosing $ x= 1/2n$ which is the point of uniform convergence. Pointwise limit is weaker, you first pick an $x$ **then** you are allowed to choose $n$ as large as you want. So in particular you choose $n$ such $1/n < x$ which makes $f_{m}(x)=0$ for all $m >n$. This makes $f_{n}(x) \to 0$ (pointwise).

Comment: What I was saying with my previous comments is that sure, you are allowed the (bad) notation $x = 1/2n$ but since it is a pointwise limit we are investigating we must look at $\lim_{m \to \infty}f_{m}(1/2n)$. That is, just because we write $x$ as something of $n$ does not mean we suddenly are looking at uniform convergence.

Comment: What about the rest of my questions @Manifoldski :)

Comment: @Manifoldski I will read your previous 3 comments (in an hour or so) thoroughly and let you know if I have any concerns